# Firebase how to apply update roles on custom child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

how to allow non authenticated user to update only highlighted child and only read other child

[image]

current roles is

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":"auth != null"
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":"auth != null",
    "$product": {
      "$id": {
        "showen":
        {
                  ".write": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```